# Populating UICollectionView cells with UIImageViews in an NSArray

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, nsarray, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView (CollectionView) embedded in a UIViewController and a UICollectionViewCell (subclass - ThemeCell) for the individual cells.

I am trying to populate each cell in the UICollectionView with an image from an NSArray of imageViews but I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[12]'
```

I have embedded a label for each cell and that works perfectly. 
Here's my plan of action.

In `ThemeCell`, I have two properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImages;
```

In the `CollectionViewCell`, I have the following code in the .h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *cView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *themeLabels;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *themeImages;
```

Here is the .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.cView.dataSource = self;
    self.cView.delegate = self;
    self.themeLabels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Default", @"Peacock", @"Purple", @"Rainbow", @"Multi Zebra", @"Green", @"Marble", @"Prosperity", @"Leopard", @"Circle", @"Slanted", @"Orange", @"Reddish", nil];
    NSLog(@"The themes are %@", self.themeLabels);

    self.themeImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Newiphonebackground.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"peacock.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepink.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rainbow.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"PinkZebra.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Greenish.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"MarblePrint.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Prosperity.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"leopard.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleEffect.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedSlanted.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"ReddishBack.png"]];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.themeLabels count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ThemeCell *themeCell = (ThemeCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Theme Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellData = [self.themeLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    themeCell.cellLabel.text = cellData;
    themeCell.cellImages.image = self.themeImages[indexPath.row];
    return themeCell;
}
```

The exception breakpoint is happening at:

```
themeCell.cellImages.image = self.themeImages[indexPath.row];
```

I have built up the CollectionView in storyboard, along with putting a cell in there and creating the outlets for the Label and UIImageView.

The labels are working really well, but the images are not and it's crashing out.

Any assistance on this would be really great and massively helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that element with index 12 (the last one) in the `self.themeImages` array is nil. Are you sure the image file name is correct and that the file exists?

Isn't its name `ReddishBlack.png` rather than `ReddishBack.png`?

Comment: Thanks so much @Antonio - That fixed the error and I can't believe I missed that. However, when the CollectionView loads, it's not showing the images in the Cell - it's just showing purple boxes (which was the colour I set the CustomCollectionViewCell to in the storyBoard. If I make that "clear", then I only get a white screen.     NSLog(@"The images are %@", self.themeImages); gives me results, but not the image names. It's giving UIImage: 0x17809f540 etc. What am I missing to get the images to display?

Comment: Sorry the image is displaying now on each cell, but now the Label in each cell has disappeared. It's not showing and I can't seem to figure out why? So the images work and display, but the label for each cell doesn't (but that does if I comment out the images).

Comment: `UIImage`s are instantiated and filled with images loaded from files - once that is done, there is no further relationship between each instance and the file it has been loaded from. The output you're getting is correct, because that means: pointer to an instance of `UIImage` whose address is `0x17809f540`.

Comment: Maybe the image overlaps the label - is that possible? Try moving the label at top and the image below it.
Have you set any layout constraint to let the image grow depending on its size?

Comment: Thanks so much @Antonio - it was the image overlapping. Really appreciate your help on this and great answers here. Thanks again!